# What permissions are required for docker host volume?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, docker

I created a docker image with mysql. I use the VOLUME command in the Dockerfile to define a mounted volume:

```
VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql/"]
```

and tell it to mount the volume when running:

```
docker run -v /media/user/encrypted/:/var/lib/mysql/ mysql_with_secrets
```

*[other parameters omitted for simplicity]*

The issue is that the container doesn't start. The container does start when mounting the volume with a folder in the home path instead of */media/user/encrypted/*. */media/user/encrypted/* is a mounted encrypted partition owned by my user and the root group.

I tried changing the ownership of the partition in various ways, but I still couldn't make the container start. What should the permissions be in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to identify the userid of the process running inside the container and chown the volume path to that userid OR make the volume global-writable (first one recommended). If your image (meaning the userid inside) changes at any point though, this will break.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I wish only you had answered instead of commented, so that I could mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I made it an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the userid of the process running inside the container and chown the volume path to that userid OR make the volume global-writable (first one recommended). If your image (meaning the userid inside) changes at any point though, this will break.